# Adding custom video player to site

Tags: html, iframe, media-player

I have a problem adding a video player that I created in playerjs.com to my site
using this `<iframe src="//site.com/player/player.html?file=//plrjs.com/x.mp4" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`. When I add player link of film from another site I get this error: [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCsUH.png) .
I am using DLE 1.50 Template on infinityfree host is is there way to add custom player without gettin this error?

Comment: try it in google chrome. then see if it works....iframe and JS can be turned on and off for diff browsers. Lastly, When developing a solution for the web...it is normal to see unique requirements per browser. stuff that works on chrome may not work on Firefox...stuff that works in safari may not work in the others. you got to test in the browsers you need your apps to work in.

Comment: it doesn't work in chrome too it says infinityfree.net refused to connect.

Comment: //site.com.....are you trying to route to a url for your app? why is this not http:// or https://

Comment: no i just typed site.com here in code i wrote http://sheiqmenishenikargimovtyan.rf.gd instead of site.com